# Unable to get the address of my location from latitude and longitude on button click in android

Tags: android, google-maps

i have written a program to print the latitude and longitude of my location and the latitude and longitude are shopwing properly , but unforunately i am not able to retieve the address of my locaiton with the help of same latitude and longitude , need some help please , no error also showing up.
I also tried using addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) but same result.
Here gpsTracker is the object of my GPSTracker class , which i used to show my latitude and longitude ,which is working perfectly.

Code for the above :

```
bDetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                        Locale.getDefault());

                List<Address> addresses = null;
                double latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
                addresses = geocoder
                        .getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String areaName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                // String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String pincode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                // String stateName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                String countryName = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

                if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
                    txtadd.setText("Waiting for Location");
                } else {
                    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                        txtadd.setText("Area Name :" + areaName + "\n"
                                + "\n" + "PinCode :" + pincode + "\n"
                                + "\n" + "Country Name:" + countryName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

can anyone suggest any change that i have to make so that i would be able to display the address of my location ?

Comment: Side note: I am always impressed seeing people not removing `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private String getAddressString(double latitude, double longitude) {
    String strAddress = "";
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                longitude, 1);
        if (addresses != null) {
            Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnAddress = new StringBuilder("");

            for (int i = 0; i < returnAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnAddress
                        .append(returnAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                "\n");
            }
            strAddress = strReturnAddress.toString();
            Log.w("address",
                    "" + strReturnAddress.toString());
        } else {
            Log.w("address", "No Address found!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("address", "Can't get Address!");
    }
    return strAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have internet connection because only with internet you can get address. 
In other case try to change coordinates. Maybe your place has no address.